# Introductory Text to Partial Differential Equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I've been searching for a text suitable as an introduction to partial differential equations however all the texts I have come across are with conflicting opinions. I have a decent basis upon for regarding mathematics, such as calculus, linear algebra, and a good understanding of ordinary differential equations. However, I do not have a very good basis in the proofs of regarding the concepts I have learned. This is making finding a book which is at an introductory level and does not assume a great deal of prior knowledge more difficult to find.

I am genuinely interested in the topic and welcome to suggestions on how to properly build a basis of wholistic understanding. Any text which provides the basis for understanding without assuming a great deal of prior knowledge is also welcome as I am not worried on how long it will take me to understand rather that the material for me to be able to understand is presented.

I understand there have been similar questions asked to the Mathematics Stack Exchange however I wanted to hear what the community has to say regarding my particular situation. Any clarity as to which is most suitable as an introduction and/or best overall is welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For undergraduate level, the book "Partial Differential Equations An Introduction" by Walter A. Strauss is decent and is highly recommended